# What is the sum of the second numbers in the first $100$ rows of Pascal's triangle (excluding the first row)?

Tags: binomial-coefficients

> What is the sum of the second numbers in the first $100$ rows of Pascal's triangle (excluding the first row, the row containing a single $1$)? The sum should be from the second to the hundredth row.

[image: Pascal's triangle]

Starting from the second row, I initially thought this meant you count from the left two numbers. So it would be $$1+2+3+4+\cdots+99$$ This means I get $4950$. I thought this would be too simple of a solution.

Could someone tell me if the addition I did above is all the question is asking from me?

Comment: Except that perhaps the question wants you to use rows 2 through 101 (excluding the first row from the count of rows), that seems like a reasonable interpretation.

Comment: @rogerl, the question as it appears now specifically says to add up $99$ numbers (from “the second to hundredth row”), not $100$. In other words, “the first 100 rows ... excluding the first row” is meant to specify $99$ rows, as opposed to what I think you surmised. (So it’s the “first 100 ... excluding,” and not “first 100 ... commencing with.”)

Comment: Then I think your answer is correct.

Answer (score 1):

To make the computations more transparent, I'll start indexing with 0. Therefore we want to sum up the elements $a_{k,1}$ ($k\geq 1$).
I'll also assume, that the elements, that are 'outside' of the triangle are all equal 0 (in particular $a_{k,k+1}=0$ and $a_{0,1}=a_{0,2}=a_{1,2}=0$)

Note, that for $n\geq 1$ we have:
$$a_{n,2}=a_{n-1,1}+a_{n-1,2}$$
Therefore by consecutive replacing the element $a_{*,2}$ on the right side with analogical value, we obtain
$$a_{n,2}=a_{n-1,1}+a_{n-2,1}+...+a_{1,1}+a_{0,1}$$
We have then the sum of $n$ elements with he index 1 from the first $n$ rows.

Of course $a_{i,j}=\binom{i}{j}$

For $n=100$ we have then:
$$\sum_{k=0}^{99}a_{k,1}=a_{100,2}=\binom{100}{2}$$